# Can't ssh to my local VM (timeout)

Tags: virtual-machine, putty

I'm using an old redhat virtual machine with VMware Player.

I used to be able to connect it using `PuTTY`, but for some reason now I can't.

Here's what I do:

1. I use `ifconfig` to get the IP address
2. I ping the IP address and get a response just to make sure
3. I check that `iptables` accepts TCP connections through port 22
4. I use `PuTTY` to connect to the IP address I got from step 2

It used to work, now it doesn't. I didn't change anything but everytime I reset the `iptables` rules gets deleted and I have to redo it, but it still doesn't work. I get "connection timed out" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Timeouts are usually due to the server being down. Try to restart sshd service on the VM

Comment: Along with the suggestion from @AndreiTumbar you could temporarily stop the iptables service completely, as a troubleshooting step.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know RedHat uses firewalld and not iptables. That might be why your rule is getting reseted.
You can check by running `systemctl status firewalld`. If it is you can open ssh by running `firewall-cmd --add-port=22/tcp --permanent`.
That should open the port in your Firewall.

Another thing is, that root is not permitted to log in via ssh by default. You have to set `PermitRootLogin Yes` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf` and reload the ssh config with `systemctl reload sshd`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).